# String slicing: removing 1st and 2nd last element from the string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know is there a way to slice string in python so that we can ignore 1st and 2nd last character ?

eg:

```
query = "'select * from tableName where name='Raj'';"
print(query) #Output as 'select * from tableName where name='Raj'';

#output needed: select * from tableName where name='Raj';
```

If I use string slicing as :

```
print(query[1:-2]) #output as select * from tableName where name='Raj'
```

I want output ending with `;` but I dont want to concatenate this string
way around could be as below but I dont want that way as it requires concatenation

```
print(query[1:-2]+';') #output as select * from tableName where name='Raj';
```

There are lots of links, but couldn't find this way, any solutions ?

Comment: There's no way to get non-contiguous slices with irregular intervals in vanilla python. What's wrong with doing `query[1:-2] + query[-1]`?

Comment: strings are immutable so i'm afraid there's no way around this. with lists you could delete ranges of the list _inside_ the list. possible here but you have to convert to list, do that and join back to string...

Comment: "but I dont want to concatenate this string way around" Why not? "as it requires concatenation" And why is that a problem?

Comment: I think you're doing premature optimization.  Your code is calling SQL.  The time it takes to generate the correct query string is virtually irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @user, My motive is to add the sql query used  as an insert statement (column is Clob type) and also execute using python. I wanted to use minimum possible codes. if I need to add ; at the end but dont want quotes around statement. I am also facing issues while adding where clause. I will try again from my end, will ping again . thanks again

Comment: @Elyes Lounissi, thanks for correcting my grammar